# Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.7.0 Authentication Required

Tags: laravel, smtp

Estoy haciendo un backend con Laravel para enviar correos, estoy usando postman para probar la API.

al mandar el nombre y el telefono por postman me da este error = Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at
530 5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError q11sm12242304wrv.67 - gsmtp
" in file /var/www/html/laravelsend/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/AbstractSmtpTransport.php on line 457

el archivo .env de laravel lo tengo asi.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=micorreo@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

En mi gmail tengo habilitada la opción de app less secure, no tengo habilitada la doble autentificacion.

¿que puedo hacer para que se envie el correo?

Comment: Prueba limpar la cache de configuración  `php artisan config:clear` o recacheandola `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: ya hice eso y no me funciona

Answer (score 1):

Lo he solucionado poniendo en mail.php

'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME','kjlkjkl@gmail.com'),
 'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD','uiuiuiui'),